# MessageBird reportUrl not triggered

Tags: messagebird

I am trying to send a conversation message, I able to receive the message but I didn't get the report, I configured reportUrl, but the report doesn't arrive, why?
I checked into /var/www/apache2/access.log, I got below:

35.246.41.39 - - [01/Jun/2021:11:24:44 +0000] "POST /whatsapp/myWebhookAsync? HTTP/1.1" 200 5327 "-" "MessageBirdHTTPQueue/1622459790-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

my webhook is only simple, I just want to log it into a file, just want to make sure if it really arrives or not

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/WhatsApp/myWebhookAsync")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task myWebhookAsync()
    {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
            {
                string _jsonx = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                await Helper.SaveLogAsync("CAPTURED --- WhatsAppController.MessageBird_ReportAsync " + _jsonx);
            }

    }
```

Comment: Hey Don2 - sorry to hear you are not getting any updates to the `reportUrl`. 
Would you please be able to [submit a request](https://support.messagebird.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=360000129578) with our MessageBird support team so we help troubleshoot this issue?

If you can include some information about what endpoint you are using, or if you are using our SDK to send the message it would be useful to our support team!

Thanks!

Comment: submitted.. thank you